# Query from a script editor

Tags: web-part, query

I need to use a script editor to display list data.  The content query web part will display the data the exact way I need to have it display but I need to use a script editor web part on my site - is there a way that I can have the script editor display the results from the content query?

Any advise is welcome.

Anngie

Comment: Your scenario does not have enough information for others to help you, I would suggest you provide additional information regarding your data structure and what end goal you have for others to provide additional feedback.

Comment: I want to display queried list items using a script editor.  is this possible

Comment: Like, there are a lot of ways to display list items. You can simply use a list webpart if the CQWP cannot be used. You can use a script editor to include a script that combs all the relevant data and spit it back out to whichever way you want it. It is not impossible, but it's a lot of work. Or you can approach it using a dataview webpart instead. All these have their advantages and their shortcomings. Without knowing your scenario, I don't think I would tell you that script editor can display results from the content query, but there are ways to achieve something similar.

Comment: What is the justification for using a script editor web part when the cqwp will do the trick? It sounds like jumping through hoops for No reasons...

Comment: I am currently using a CQWP, which works fine.  I want it in another area that is controlled by a .js file.  This area uses script editors well but no other web part will show as the .js code overrides everything else ... so I just want to know how to display list items in a script editor web part.  Can it be done?  and if so, how?

Comment: As previously stated, more information is needed to help you resolve your issue. What "area" are you talking about? What does the .js code actually do? How is the .js file attached to the page? Without understanding that, it will be hard have good answers for your case, because we simply do not and cannot possibly know.